# collapsing pandas dataframe by ranges of duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

```
    test_df = pd.DataFrame({'pos' : [x for x in range(10)],
                            'A' : ['foo' for x in range(5)] + ['bar' for x in range(5)],
                            'B' : ['foo' for x in range(3)] + ['bar' for x in range(7)]})
```

makes:

```
pos    A    B
0  foo  foo
1  foo  foo
2  foo  foo
3  foo  bar
4  foo  bar
5  bar  bar
6  bar  bar
7  bar  bar
8  bar  bar
9  bar  bar
```

I am trying to summarize ranges of duplicated rows like this where `start` and `stop` represent the range of pos for duplicates in col A and B

```
start stop A B
0 3 foo foo
3 5 foo bar
5 9 bar bar
```

how do I do this?

I think I am close with this:

```
# collapse regions
collapse = test_df[~test_df.duplicated(subset=test_df.columns[2:],keep='first')].copy()
collapse1 = test_df[~test_df.duplicated(subset=test_df.columns[2:], keep='last')].copy()

collapse['stop'] = collapse1['pos'].to_list()
collapse = collapse.rename(columns={'pos' : 'start'})
collapse = collapse[['start', 'stop', 'A', 'B']]
```

but can't quite figure out how to make it just as want I want as indicated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try groupby

```
test_df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'pos': ['first', 'last']}).reset_index()

     A    B   pos     
            first last
0  bar  bar     5    9
1  foo  bar     3    4
2  foo  foo     0    2
```

if you want to get rid of the multi-indexed columns then

```
new_df = test_df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'pos': ['first', 'last']})
new_df.columns = ['start', 'stop']
new_df = new_df.reset_index()

     A    B  start  stop
0  bar  bar      5     9
1  foo  bar      3     4
2  foo  foo      0     2
```

Comment: Named agg can get you directly to you second option: `new_df = test_df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).agg(start=('pos', 'first'), stop=('pos', 'last'))`